# How to implement grpc server in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, grpc

How to implement grpc server in spring boot? I have two classes the server and client of a demo application. below the two classes:

GrpcClient:

```
package com.example.demo;

import io.grpc.ManagedChannel;
import io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder;

public class GrpcClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 8080)
                .usePlaintext()
                .build();

        HelloServiceGrpc.HelloServiceBlockingStub stub
                = HelloServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);

        HelloResponse helloResponse = stub.hello(HelloRequest.newBuilder()
                .setFirstName("Rafael")
                .setLastName("Fernando")
                .build());


        channel.shutdown();
    }
}
```

GrpcServer:

```
package com.example.demo;

import com.example.demo.services.HelloServiceImpl;
import io.grpc.Server;
import io.grpc.ServerBuilder;
import java.io.IOException;


public class GrpcServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Server server = ServerBuilder
                .forPort(8080)
                .addService(new HelloServiceImpl()).build();

        server.start();
        server.awaitTermination();

    }
}
```

The two classes plus my service I get this to work. My question is the following how to implement the grpc server in spring boot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've launched a project called [grpc-starter](https://github.com/DanielLiu1123/grpc-starter). The goal of this project is to enable smoother integration between the gRPC ecosystem and Spring Boot, it embraces Spring Boot 3. The main features include:

- Autoconfiguration for gRPC server/client
- JSON transcoder
- Integration with [proto-gen-validate](https://github.com/bufbuild/protoc-gen-validate)
- Exception handling
- Dynamic refreshing

Here's a simple example:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableGrpcClients("io.grpc")
public class SimpleApp extends SimpleServiceGrpc.SimpleServiceImplBase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(SimpleApp.class)
                .properties("grpc.client.authority=127.0.0.1:9090")
                .run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void unaryRpc(SimpleRequest request, StreamObserver<SimpleResponse> responseObserver) {
        SimpleResponse response = SimpleResponse.newBuilder()
                .setResponseMessage("Hello " + request.getRequestMessage())
                .build();
        responseObserver.onNext(response);
        responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(SimpleServiceGrpc.SimpleServiceBlockingStub stub) {
        return args -> {
            SimpleResponse response = stub.unaryRpc(SimpleRequest.newBuilder().setRequestMessage("World!").build());
            System.out.println(response.getResponseMessage());
        };
    }

}
```

Worth a try!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but I've already managed to use the io.grpc library @daniel

Comment: Just a question, can you use @Bean in this project of yours?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what 'can you use @Bean in this project of yours' means.

All beans in this project adhere to the Spring bean lifecycle. If you are familiar with Spring Boot, you should be able to get started quickly.

Comment: I asked because of this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77119234/how-to-use-autowired-in-grpc-endpoint-created-with-io-grpc-libraries?noredirect=1#comment135957656_77119234

Comment: Of course!
You can use `@Component` to register grpc and `@Autowired` to inject grpc stub.

Comment: but what would my `.addService(new CartPurchaseQueryImpl())` look like with @Component?

Comment: You don't need `.addService(new CartPurchaseQueryImpl())` manually if you're using [`grpc-starter`](https://github.com/DanielLiu1123/grpc-starter), just use `@Component` and the framework will auto register all your services. Here is an [example](https://github.com/DanielLiu1123/grpc-starter/tree/main/examples/simple) you can refer to.

Comment: It's just that I want to do this without third-party libraries. Is there any solution with the io.grpc library? Thanks for the feedback

Comment: it has been resolved, thank you all for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

You can use [grpc-spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/yidongnan/grpc-spring-boot-starter) or [LogNet's grpc-spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter) libraries to configure your service/client implementations, interceptors, and server with Spring's look and feel. These two are the only ones listed on the official [spring-boot-starters list](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters).

If you don't care about that "Spring look and feel" you can just implement your services/stubs as classes annotated with `@Service` and `@Component`, register them and their interceptors if any, and start the server at boot in your `@SpringBootApplication` class.

Comment: Is there a way to use just the "io.grpc" library without calling other people's libraries? I made this example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76410367/i-created-a-grpc-with-spring-boot-using-libraries-from-the-io-grpc-repository) not sure if it's right