# How to use @Autowired in grpc endpoint created with io.grpc libraries

Tags: spring-boot, grpc-java

How to use @Autowired in grpc endpoint created with io.grpc libraries. I have a grpc server and client but I can't inject classes into it with @Bean, @Component, @Service it just doesn't work.

follow the code from my grpc server:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CartPurchaseQueryApplication implements ApplicationRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CartPurchaseQueryApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        //Crie o servidor gRPC
        SocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("springboot", 30010);
        Server server = NettyServerBuilder.forAddress(address)
                .addService(new CartPurchaseQueryImpl())
                .intercept(new JWTInterceptor())
                .build();

        // Inicie o servidor
        server.start();

        // Aguarde a finalização do servidor
        server.awaitTermination();
    }
}
```

My grpc service endpoints:

```
@Service
public class CartPurchaseQueryImpl extends CartPurchaseQueryGrpc.CartPurchaseQueryImplBase{

     @Autowired
     CategoryProductRepository cartPurchaseQueryRepository;
}
```

My Autowired gives the null message
Does anyone know how to help me? I am very grateful.

Comment: Add the stack trace currently its imposible to see nothing what could give us a hint about what is failling

Comment: I understand, I am creating repository and services without dependency injection. @AdrianLagartera thanks for the feedback

Comment: Is CategoryProductRepository an annotated component or is defined in a configuration class?

Comment: Not the repository, I use mongoTemplate, I manually instantiate it and create queries with it.I do it this way because other methods don't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Comment: I'll test it but some I've already tried, I'll look at this post better later, thank you @dan1st

Comment: The post essentially sais that `@Autowired` is ignored if you are instantiating the service with `new` (`new CartPurchaseQueryImpl()`) and that you need to autowire `CartPurchaseQueryImpl` instead.

Comment: I tried this way: `@Autowired
CartPurchaseQueryImpl cartPurchaseQuery;` and
`Server server = NettyServerBuilder.forAddress(address)
.addService(cartPurchaseQuery)
.intercept(new JWTInterceptor())
.build();` but it gives me an error when injecting: **Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findAll(java.lang.Class)" because "this.mongoTemplate" is null** @dan1st

Comment: Make sure you are properly autowiring the bean using `MongoTemplate` as stated in the linked post.

Comment: `@Service
public class CartPurchaseQueryImpl extends CartPurchaseQueryGrpc.CartPurchaseQueryImplBase{     @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;` my code

Comment: Another error that is giving: `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.cartpurchasequery.service.impl.CartPurchaseQueryImpl]: Constructor threw exception`

Comment: it has been resolved, thank you all for your feedback